# Unable to make private geth node online

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I am currently working on building my own private network on Ethereum to build small apps. I am learning as I go so excuse me if this question is very obvious, but I have exhausted myself looking for solution over the internet and at geth docs, but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to make my private network with my own id, and make the nodes online so that they can see eachother. I have tried making two nodes on different laptops and different Internets, and also tried deploying a node on my AWS EC2 Instance of Linux Ubuntu (this is my final objective).

Here is what I have tried so far:

- I am running geth with same genesis everywhere - 3x windows machines and 1x linux machine.
- I have used --rpc, --rpcaddr, --rpcport, --rpccorsdomain, --http, --httpaddr, --httpport, --ws, --wsaddr, --wsport flags (in different iterations).
- I have used --nat flag with extip as well.

When I run multiple nodes on multiple machines, the `admin.nodeInfo.enode` outputs my enode address with external IP, but when I add that IP to another machine using `admin.addPeer` it returns true (means the enode address is valid) but never reaches the node.

However, for what it's worth, I am able to add two nodes and communicate with eachother on local network only, but it does not work on remote IP. I am either missing something very basic or... I am missing something very basic. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a firewall? Are you behind a NAT network? It might require to open required ports or else you will not be able to connect. You can add `--verbosity 4`  to geth command line to increase diagnostic messages.

Comment: Hey Ismael thanks for your response. Yes, I did check my firewall I disabled it temporarily as well as added in/out rules for it. I have a little knowledge of networks too so I went on to debug with --verbosity 6. I noticed one of the messages said "the target machine actively refused connection" or something like that.

Comment: That usually means that the target machine has a firewall or it is behind a nat. You have to configure the firewall/nat to allow pass-through the p2p port.

Comment: Yes Ismael, I did manually add inbound and outbound rules on firewall as well, still no success.